# wordpress ait-theme remove the item slug from the URL

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, url-rewriting, slug

I am using the directory2 Theme for wordpress, which is written in ait-theme framework.

I have installed my wordpress in a subdirectory /var/www/web/company:

```
http://example.com/company/
```

is my site and home url of wordpress.

I have a new Item in the way: /company/google

Now to see the item I need to call:

```
http://example.com/company/company/google
```

but

I want to have the URL:

```
http://example.com/company/google
```

Is this possible?